# Access data with Realm Browser

Tags: realm, nsdata, realm-browser

I'm saving `data` in my Realm database.
Is it posible to access these datas? They are images and I would like to preview it.

Answer (score 0):

The Realm Browser doesn't support to preview images yet, unfortunately. Such features on the list tracked by ["Display common binary data formats"](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/23)

Comment: Can I have access to these datas through the browser?

Comment: No. `Data` properties just appear like `<Data>` currently.